# Chabad Shachrit late

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sources-mekorot, chabad

I would like to know what is the Halachic SOURCE for chabad to daven late for shachrit.
I have asked many people who should know and have been unsatisfied by their answers.
If anyone could help , it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: The Chabads I've been to all start davening after zman tefillah.

Comment: Rami, welcome to Mi Yodeya! As noted by @Michoel, you are fortunate in that your question was answered here before you even got here! I hope you'll look around and find other information here of interest, perhaps including our 71 other questions about [tag:chabad]. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Finally, don't miss [*Purim - Mi Yodeya?*](http://s.tk/miyodeya)!